# how to use std::copy for array of struct with values deep inside

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
struct Base
{
  float value;
};
struct Metre
{
  Base base;
};
struct Distance
{
  std::array<Metre, 4> distances;
};

std::array<float, 4> values{10.0, 11.23, 12.34, 23.45 };
Distance dist;

std::copy(std::cbegin(values), std::cend(values),  std::begin(dist.distances)->base.value);
```

Need to copy values into dist.distances[]->base.value and also from dist.distances[]->base.value to values

Getting compiler error:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:377:57: error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<float>’
       typedef typename iterator_traits<_II>::value_type _ValueTypeI;
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:379:64: error: no type named ‘iterator_category’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<float>’
       typedef typename iterator_traits<_II>::iterator_category _Category;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your intention is copy the values from the `values` array in the `dist.distances` array.

A possible solution pass through `std::transform()`

```
std::transform(values.cbegin(), values.cend(), dist.distances.begin(),
               [](float f){ return Metre{ Base{f} }; });
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP asks

> how to copy from dist.distances to values?

Again: with `std::transform()`

```
std::transform(dist.distances.cbegin(), dist.distances.cend(), values.begin(),
               [](Metre const & m){ return m.base.value; });
```

Comment: how to copy from dist.distances to values?

Comment: @ReshmaDhotre - answer improved; hope this helps.